# Am I writing Flutter code in the correct style?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm cleaning up my Flutter code and I'm not sure if I'm writing my Flutter code in the correct style.

First, here's my code to import the file:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import 'package:project/src/common_widgets/custom_text_form_field.dart';
import 'package:project/src/common_widgets/generic_button.dart';
```

Here is the code for my `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

---

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void name(params) {}

    return Container();
  }
}
```

---

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

---

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void name(params) {}

    return Container();
  }
}
```

Feel free to comment if you need more code to check it out!

Am I writing Flutter code in the correct style?

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: @BCdotWEB sorry, I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: What does your code do? Does it summon spirits, is it a recipe for a banana milkshake? The current title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3):

*Note, the reason I was able to answer so quickly is because this was originally [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74979216/12349734) (now deleted) - to which I redirected the OP to here*.

You haven't really shared enough code, but:

##### Imports

Your imports should be relative imports (See [Flutter imports : relative path or package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693195/flutter-imports-relative-path-or-package)
).

Meaning, instead of:

```
import 'package:project/src/common_widgets/custom_text_form_field.dart';
```

should be:

```
import './project/src/common_widgets/custom_text_form_field.dart';
```

##### Functions

Your function:

```
void name(params) {}
```

Is defined *within* your `build` method, so for every rebuild, the entire function will be recreated. And additionally, any values set in there will be reset every rebuild, i.e. every `setState`.

Now, your example was with a function, but I commonly see this mistake of holding variables within the `build` method. Take for example:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _value = false;
    return Switch(
        value: _value,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
          });
        });
  }
```

The value of `_value` will never be changed from `false` to `true` since every update of the UI - (calling `setState`) would just reset the value to `false`.